# What entities can a lambda use without capturing it?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation) I read the following

> A lambda expression can use a variable without capturing it if the variable
>
> - is a non-local variable or has static or thread local [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (in which case the variable cannot be captured), or
> - is a reference that has been initialized with a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Constant_expression).
>
> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable
>
> - has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been initialized with a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Constant_expression), or
> - is constexpr and has no mutable members.

As regards the first bullet, I think this is a relevant example

```cpp
int x = 17; // non-local variable
static int y = 17; // variable wht static storage duration (am I correct?)
int main () {
    auto g = [x, y] // error for both, emptying the capture fixes the error
             { (void)(x + y); };
}
```

As regards the third bullet, I think this is an example for it (`int` can be changed to an `enum`, I understand)

```cpp
struct C{};
int main () {
    int nc{}; // non const => need capture
    constexpr int ce{3};
    int const cce{ce}; // const init-ed with constexpr => not need to capture
    int const cn{nc}; // const init-ed with non-constexpr => need capture
    int const volatile cv{}; // const but volatile => need capture
    C const c{};
    auto lam = [c, nc, cn, cv]{
        (void)(nc + cce + cn + cv);
        (void)c;
    };
    lam();
}
```

However, as regards the second bullet, I don't really understand what *a reference that has been initialized with a constant expression* is. I don't think it is something like this:

```cpp
constexpr int x{3};
int const&/* this is a reference */ y = x/* this is a constant expression */;
```

Also the fourth is unclear to me. I thought the following would be erroneous because of that point, but it is just fine:

```cpp
constexpr struct M {
    mutable int x;
} m{3};

int main () {
    auto lam = []{
        (void)m;
    };
    lam();
}
```

I'd really like if the answer would explain the matter with reference to [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda).

Comment: You don't know the difference between "use" and "read"?

Comment: @NicolBolas, probably I don't know the precise meaning of either of them. Off the top of my head I'd say that `[…](…){…}` uses `x` as soon as `x` appears somewhere in `{…}` (which would also mean a lambda uses its params). "Read"? No, I don't know what it means that a lambda reads something. I just suspect it has nothing at all to do with `std::cin`.

Comment: "*probably I don't know the precise meaning of either of them*" Cppreference is a reference site, not the C++ standard. The meaning of them is exactly what the words say. And I have no idea why you associate `cin` with "read the value of a variable". It reads from standard input, not from variables. I feel like there's some kind of over-analysis happening here, over-thinking something that is really quite simple.

Comment: Nit-picking note: the term, "the Standard" should have a capital "S".

Comment: @AdrianMole, not quite because I linked to the draft? :P

Comment: @NicolBolas, well, I still don't understand what it means that a lambda reads something. I don't see how it is different from making use of the value of an entity. Forgive my stupidity.

Comment: @Enlico i think "use" merely means that a lambda can not only "read" but also write to the variable.

Comment: It's still a 'special' paper ... the Draft.

Comment: @Enlico: "*I still don't understand what it means that a lambda reads something.*" Again, I feel like you're over-thinking this. Do you know what it means for *anything* to read from a variable? Like, the expression `x + 5`; do you think that reads from the variable? If I were to put that expression in a lambda, would it not be reasonable to say that the lambda reads from the variable?

Comment: In your first example, `x` and `y` both have static storage duration; `static` is badly overloaded: in that context it causes internal linkage, not any storage duration.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind, thank you very much, I was indeed not attentive.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, now it's clear to me. I had understood what _read_ meant, but at the same time I was thinking "what can _use_ mean other than _read_?". Well, write.